# Are java static fields allocated multiple times when threading?

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, static

I am working on a group project in which we have several static constants declared in a Worker class. Multiple threads of this worker are spawned and our java application seems to be using a huge amount of memory. I am wondering if this is a result of each thread allocating more of these static constants, but I am not sure.

Comment: Just an idea. There _could_ be a problem with hot deployment, with lingering old class instances. An app server restart should show this.

Comment: @MikeBaranczak In programming, "variable," often means any named quantity whether or not it varies. In cplusplus.com a variable is defined as such: ["we can define a variable as a portion of memory to store a determined value"](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/)... there is hardly anything said about whether or not something varies. Semantically speaking, in the English language it's either a variable or a constant, but in programming lingo it's not really an oxymoron to say "constant variable."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is only one instance of a static variable per ClassLoader.

```
 public class Foo {
      // only 1 of these
      private static int bar = 10;
 }
```

However, it is important to realize that this doesn't mean that the value is automagically synchronized.  If the threads are changing this value then it needs to be `synchronized` otherwise they could see different values according to race conditions.

Comment: These variables are final, so I'm not worried about that. I guess this hints at a different memory problem.

Comment: @DanQ Didn't think so but that was for posterity.

Answer (score 1):

Static variables are explicitly *not* allocated depending on the number of threads. Instead, static variables are allocated once within the ClassLoader.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a "huge" amount of memory e.g. many GB, I would use a memory profiler to find what the cause is and fix it if you can.  If you are using a few hundred MB, I wouldn't worry about it unless you know this is a problem.